# SSL errors when connecting skyvia to YugabyteDB YSQL

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I'm trying to connect my yugabytedb database with skyvia (as a PostgreSQL connection), but I'm getting the following error:

```
no pg_hba.conf entry for host "40.118.246.204", user "admin", database "skyvia_test", SSL off
```

According to skyvia docs, I have to add some lines to `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf`. Any idea how I would do this in yugabytedb? ([link to skyvia docs page](https://docs.skyvia.com/connections/how-to-configure-local-database-server-to-access-it-from-skyvia.html))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using YugabyteDB Managed, make sure you're connecting with SSL enabled. Set `ssl-mode` to `verify-full` and provide the certificate that you can download from the portal:

- https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/yugabyte-cloud/cloud-connect/connect-client-shell/
- https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/yugabyte-cloud/cloud-connect/connect-applications/

If you're running on your premises, then you need to pass the `ysql_hba_conf_csv` flag with that IP to a tserver instance upon startup: https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/secure/enable-authentication/ysql_hba_conf-configuration/.

This is a step-by-step video tutorial: https://youtu.be/zwQoM-ULNo8